# How to regex (1.2.3)?

Tags: php, regex

I need to search documents for a bit of text with this format:

```
(#.#.#) ex; (1.4.6)
```

As simple as this may appear, it is outside my regex skills.

Comment: It can be `/\(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\)/`

Comment: I also suffer from regex fever regularly LOL,but this is my try.. `/\([0-9]{1}.[0-9]{1}.[0-9]{1}\)/`. And i am pretty sure there maybe a thousand ways better than this :P

Comment: btw you have not told whether it can only 1 digit or also be like `25.58.446`

Comment: It can have single or double digits.

Comment: @Varun a few regex tips. `\d` is equal to `[0-9]` (in most processors) `{1}` is not needed because it will find `1` without that. The `.` needs to be escaped, `\.`, because otherwise it will mean "any character".

Comment: @chris85 Thanks buddy,i need a lot of them :p

Comment: anubhava - That worked. Feel free to post it as the answer.

Comment: How about:  (\d\.){2}\d
This says "digit-period twice, followed by digit."
If you want more than one digit, add a plus after each \d.  For a maximum length, say 8 digits, add {1,8} after each \d.  And finally, my soapbox candidate, if running in production or anywhere efficiency is a consideration, please be sure to use non-capturing groups for quantification:  (?:\d\.){2}\d

Comment: Lee, if you only want 1 or 2 digit numbers the answers below should do that for you. The `\d+` is allowing one or more digits so `(1.222.333333333333)` would match.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following regex:

```
\(\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jO6vO9/1)

Sample PHP:

```
<?php
$str = "(1.12.12) some text (1.1.1) some other text (1.1232.1) text";
preg_match_all('/\(\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\)/',$str,$matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => (1.12.12)
            [1] => (1.1.1)
        )

)
```

If you want can have any number of digits (>0) , use following regex:

```
\(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\)
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this ?

```
$int = preg_match("/\(\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\)/", "(11.2.33)", $matches);
```

You can test it here http://micmap.org/php-by-example/en/function/preg_match

Comment: correct, I saw a popup saying someone just posted an answer as I was writing mine, that must have been yours then